# Write a synthesis of the group’s individual summaries

Tags: meaning, word-choice

When checking on the midterm progress report form I received from my teacher, I came across this line:

> Write a synthesis of the group’s individual summaries

Can anyone make any sense out of this? Is this utter nonsense or am I overthinking it?
Thank you.

Comment: Examine the summary made by each group member, and produce a fusion of their ideas. Suppose you are a manager who has asked department heads for their reports, so that you can submit a single report to the directors. They might agree on some things, but have diverse opinions on others.

Comment: What is a "group"?  What is an "individual" within the group?  What is a "summary"?  What is a "synthesis"?

Comment: @HotLicks Do you agree that the sentence is poorly built?

Comment: @MisterTusk - It could be better, but should be understandable, *if you do a little research*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your teacher meant, "Write a summary of the group's individual summaries." but didn't want to use "summary" twice.

Comment: Or perhaps the teacher meant "synopsis".

Comment: And didn't want to use “précis“